# DSS boxcarring from BPS, BPELFault: SOAP body doesn't contain required part

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, bpel

When using the boxcarring functions of DSS from BPS, I get errors when starting/ending a session:

```
 org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELFault: SOAP body doesn't contain required part
```

This seems to be because the SOAP body when returning from the call is empty. Is this a known bug?

I made my way around it in the bpel process by altering the wsdl and removing the return en fault mappings, but that does not seem a proper solution to me.

Comment: IMO your approach is correct way to solve this. Other way is fix the DSS service to return a valid message (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

IMO your approach is correct way to solve this. Other way is fix the DSS service to return a valid message (if possible).

Comment: The thing about the boxcarring service, is that according to the WSDL, there should be a return element. This is wat is returned:

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

According to soapui, this is invalid and should contain an element:

`line -1: Missing message part with name [{http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice}DATA_SERVICE_RESPONSE]`

So I think this should be solved in DSS. BPEL also judges the response to be invalid.

Comment: Second problem is that I should probably use the returned JSESSIONID  to make sure we are in the same session.